# std::getline for a comma delimited table file with quotations around certain fields

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm basically running the following code. This code goes through line by line and grabs the different fields of a generic comma-delimited table file. My problem is that sometimes the "title" field can have commas in it. When it does, it's surrounded by quotation marks like so: "this, this is my title".
But when my code sees the comma, it just treats everything after it like the next field. Not all titles have quotes around them, only the ones with commas in them. My problem is that I have no idea how to make the code check for this.... How can I get my code to check for this issue?

Thanks a lot, yall. It kind of means a lot to my gainful employment!

```
while (getline(BookLine, ImpLine, '\n'))  // Get each line
{
   // create a string stream from the standard string
   std::istringstream StrLine(ImpLine);

   std::string
   bookNumber,
   chk,
   author,
   title,
   edition;

   // Parse lines
   std::getline(StrLine,bookNumber,',');
   std::getline(StrLine,chk,',');
   std::getline(StrLine,author,',');
   std::getline(StrLine,title,',');            
   std::getline(StrLine,edition,',');
}
```

Comment: So, you want quote-aware comma tokenisation. Nasty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing this well is kind of complex. Basically, you read the first character. If it's not a quote, then you read to the next comma. If it is a quote, you read to the next quote. Then you peek at the *next* character, and see if it's another quote. If it is, you read to the next quote *again*, and add what you read onto the end of what you read the first time, but without one of the quotes (i.e., a quote in a quoted string is represented by two consecutive quote marks). When you get to a quote that's followed by something other than a quote (should normally be a comma) you're reached the end of that field.

Comment: The bit about embedded quotes assumes the input is actually proper CSV, but there are lots of CSV-like files out there that don't follow that format (e.g. escaping the embedded quote, not allowing any, switching to single quotes (if they know only one type of quote will be embedded)...).

Comment: so I stayed up half the night messing with this and that's exactly what i did. I grabbed the title, checked for a quote at the beginning, if there was one, capture the data until the next quote and then splice them together.

Comment: @Cyprus106: but you left out the important part: is it working for you?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Jerry.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it, but roughly you want...

```
std::vector<string> values;
std::string value;
bool in_quoted = false;

for (const char* p = ImpLine.c_str(); *p; ++p)
    if (*p == ',' && !in_quoted)
    {
        values.push_back(value);
        value.clear();
    }
    else if (*p == '"')
        if (in_quoted)
            if (p[1] == '"')
                value += *++p;
            else
                in_quoted = false;
        else
            in_quoted = true;
    else
        value += *p;

values.push_back(value);
```

(You may want to tweak it to trim the fields of surrounding whitespace.)

Comment: That isn't guaranteed to work if the line ends with a ", as not all string implementations will null-terminate the string internally.

Comment: @fluffy: `c_str()` is guaranteed to return a pointer to a NUL-terminated buffer, irrespective of whether the string it NUL-terminated internally.

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right - I was having a brainfart moment. Moment of studipity preserved for all to see.